# Hi i have made this tcl script to find the ids by using mql in the database, but my script is not working

Tags: database, tcl, mql

The down below is TCL script I am not sure about the script could some please help me to solve the issue.

I am getting one error - should be "proc name args body"

```
tcl;
proc {
    puts "########### Trying to find the Id's ###########"
         mql start transaction
        
         set Id {mql temp query bus 'AIRBUS_E_Document_ElectricalDiagram' * * where 'attribute[clau*].value==FALSE' select id;}
         
        set error[Catch {proc $Id} sResult]
        
        If {$error == 0}{
           puts "$Id"
        }else{
           puts "Error -$sResult"
         mql abort transaction
        }
           puts "######## Finding Id's are Completed #########"

}
```

Please let me if changes are required in here.

Comment: What does this have to do with java?

Comment: As the error suggests, It is an syntax error. Use `proc MyProcName {} {` to set an empty interface to your procedure. To be more clear, you can't define the function body before you haven't set a name and an interface with arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the repose :) what i mean is those who are handling the java they might know the (tcl,mql)  so in that case i tagged.

Comment: @TanguduSaiKrishna fine, but that's not what tags are for. Please next time don't tag unrelated languages and technologies.

Comment: @ Federico klez Culloca, Thanks for the guidance and sorry that I wont repeat again and as this is my first question so i am bit lake of posting

Answer (score 2):

1. [`proc` documentation](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/proc.htm) -- missing procname and arglist
2. [`if` documentation](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/if.htm)

   - Tcl is a word-oriented language, so it is vital that arguments to commands are separated by whitespace

     - `If {$error == 0}{` ==> `if {$error == 0} {`
     - `}else{` ==> `} else {`
3. `set error[Catch {proc $Id} sResult]`

   - again, missing space after "error"
   - I don't know what you want do to here.

See also [the rules of Tcl syntax](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm) -- there's only 12 of them, so spend some time reading that.

Comment: Is this [style guide](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tcl+Style+Guide) still recommended ?

Comment: Thank you for the corrections @glenn jackman!

Comment: @Thingamabobs The style guide is strongly recommended for Tcl's own code. You can follow whatever rules you want in your own code... but keeping close to the style guide does tend to produce readable results.